# Nginx : Second location block is redirecting to path of first location block

Tags: redirect, nginx, server, location

Here is the code I am using, I referred to tutorial given at [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04). As you can see there are two location block inside a server block but on entering the path name.com/app it is redirecting to name.com, there are two apps on my server first is running on port 3000 and another on 3001, when I am changing 3001 to any port, surprisingly instead of redirection, it gives error bad gateway ( as there is nothing on that port ).

```
server{
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name name.com www.name.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/name.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/name.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /app {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers '**STRING**$
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
}
```

Comment: The app running on `localhost:3001` is redirecting to `/`. You need to fix the app not `nginx`.

Comment: uhmm, I guess yes, just clicked, on any error it was made in way to redirect to home page, I think that is causing the error...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Richard Smith in comments, App is causing the problem.
App running on 3001, is configured to redirect ( on production env) to home page if any error (like 404 in this case happens ).